# Why is there a depression in my render even though there is none in the wireframe?

Tags: modeling

I made a rough model of a 4-legged animal. I did it using a mirror modifier to mirror the left and right sides of the animal. In object mode, I right clicked on my animal and chose "Shade Smooth". Results:

Wireframe mode:

[image: Wireframe]

Solid mode:

[image: Solid mode]

Why is there a discoloration in the center of the animal?

Rendered mode:

[image: Rendered mode]

So there is discoloration in solid mode because there is a ridge and depression in that area... But what is the cause of the ridge and depression? According to my wireframe, there is no depression in that area. The render is wrong. The head is supposed to be smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, some of your normals have become flipped causing problems with your shading. To correct this, go to edit mode, then *Select all > mesh > normals > recalculate outside*.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may have double vertices. Go to *Mesh > Clean Up > Merge By Distance* to get rid of them.

Double vertices are vertices that seem to be one vertex but are actually multiple occupying the same space. This causes discontinuations in the smoothing. *Merge By Distance* removes these double vertices.

A message should pop up saying how many vertices were removed. If none were removed, it is another problem.